# 'Charlie Bingham Gets Clocked'

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Charlie Bingham Gets Clocked

This is a name of novel.

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read the novel.

**to get clocked** is a slang verb phrase meaning 'to be knocked unconscious by a punch to the head, especially a punch to the chin'.

> They were fighting behind the gym, and he got clocked with an uppercut.

**to get clocked** can also mean 'to have one's time measured, for example, an athlete's time when running a specified distance, or a vehicle's speed on a road or highway'.

> He had to pay a large fine. He got clocked doing 50 in a school zone.

Comment: +1 The story actually involves a schoolboy's misadventures with a clock--but the title is almost certainly a tongue-in-cheek evocation of your first definition.